# Get id of a span in JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the span id in JavaScript following code always returning M26 but I want different values on different click M26 or M27:

```
function clickHandler() {
    var xid= document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    var xsp= xid[0].id;   
    alert(xsp);     
} 
}

<html>
    <BODY LANGUAGE = "javascript" onClick = "clickHandler();">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><u><b><span id=M26>2011-  
        2012</span></b></u></a>   
        <div id=c26 STYLE="display:none">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"><u><b><span id=M27>2012-  
            2013</span></b></u></a>   
        <div id=c27 STYLE="display:none"> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please fix your code before using it in a question: You have a right bracket (`}`) too many after your `clickHandler` function, and you're not closing your `div`s. Also, `LANGUAGE = "javascript` is invalid.

Comment: still too many `}` characters...

Comment: @danwellman: I didn't edit out his mistakes on purpose. He wouldn't learn from it, then.

Comment: of course, my comment was directed at the OP as he had edited the post after your comment, but this issue was still present...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that `var xid= document.getElementsByTagName("span");` gets all spans on the page regardless of where you click.

To solve this problem you should just pass a reference to the clicked object within the function.  For example:

```
<span id=M26 onclick="clickHandler(this);" >2011-2012</span>
```

Then in your javascript code:

```
function clickHandler(object) {
    alert(object.id);
}
```

However it is a good idea to bind the events within javascript rather than inline in the html tags.

This [article](http://triaslama.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/four-ways-javascript-binding-event-listeners/) describes the different ways in which you can bind events to elements.

Comment: Normally, I'd downvote inline event listeners, but considering the code in the OP, better keep it simple, right?

Comment: I´d prefer `onclick="clickHandler.call(this)"` and in your function `alert(this.id)`

Comment: @Cerbrus If you read the last sentence, it clearly states that binding in javascript rather than inline is a good idea.  However in examples such as this it is often easier to illustrate with inline handlers.

Comment: but i dont want to call method with each span if i have called it already with body tag

Comment: @JonTaylor, Yea, I saw that. Personally, I'd suggest adding a sample of how it should be done.

Comment: @user1865365 you have to explicitly set the call handler on the elements which need the interaction.  You are best to do this by looping through all spans in javascript and binding the events there.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the id of the element that has just been clicked:

Pass a reference to `this` to the handler:

```
onclick="handlerFunc(this);">
```

Or, better yet, pass the *event object* to the handler, this allows you to manipulate the event's behaviour, too:

```
onclick='handlerFunc(event);'>
//in JS:
function handlerFunc(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
    element.id;//<-- the target/source of the event (ie the element that was clicked)
    if (e.preventDefault)
    {//a couple of methods to manipulate the event
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use getAttribute() function for this...

```
function clickHandler() {
var xid= document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var xsp= xid[0].getAttribute('id');   
alert(xsp);     
} 


<html>
<body LANGUAGE = "javascript" onload = "clickHandler();">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"><u><b><span id=M26>2011-  
    2012</span></b></u></a>   
    <div id=c26 STYLE="display:none">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"><u><b><span id=M27>2012-  
        2013</span></b></u></a>   
    <div id=c27 STYLE="display:none"> 
</body>
</html>
```

[See working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/8wSKM/)

Comment: What if 10 spans used the same event handler? also: why would you scan the DOM on each click? That's just massive overkill